# Is there any documentation for Microsoft asp.net and mvc front-end scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I use the Mvc2 and its native validation system.
Some js files are included by default, for example:
MicrosoftAjax.js
MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
MicrosoftMvcValidtion.js

I need to make some more complex validation procedures, which means I need to understand these scripts.
Is there any documentation about these scripts? 
I searched thoroughly but find nothing... Microsoft doesn't document?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Microsoft's documentation is often lacking.

However, I would recommend several things:

Firstly, check out [MVC Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) validation - it may provide you with all the extra validation that you require.

Secondly, if you can upgrade to MVC3 - validation has much better support.

Thirdly, I'd recommend using the jquery support instead of the MicrosoftAjax - you'll find it's much better supported moving forward.